Facebook OpenGraph Debugger reset to zero
I am doing work on a Wordpress site. My client previously had several hundred Likes/Shares on many of her blog posts.
I recently rebuilt her site from scratch, but none of the URLs, slugs, or permalinks changed. Many of her blog posts are now showing zero Likes/Shares, when they previously had hundreds each. I am trying to determine what could have changed to cause these numbers to be reset to zero.
When I visit the Debugger, it also shows the counts at zero, and no changes I make to the submitted URL affects this. If it hasn't been scraped recently, it still has the older, high count. But if I click Scrape Again, it resets the count to zero. Every time.
Has Facebook changed how it tabulates Likes/Shares recently, in such a way that blog posts that previously had hundreds of shares will now be rest to zero? Is this affecting all users?
Thanks for any help you can provide!
I've researched this extensively, I don't see any issues with the site itself or code.
